# Dosa Batter Fermentation

Tags: indian-cuisine

How do you know when the batter is fermented enough but not too much? Is it to taste/preference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the dosa batter gets fermented, it doubles in volume and aereates well. To know if the dosa batter is over fermented, just taste a small part, it turns out sour.
To prepare dosa batter, be sure the temperature is not too hot. If it is, it won't take much time to ferment the batter (5-6 hours). Refrigerate the batter so that it does not get over fermented.

Comment: How hot is "*too hot*" (e.g. °C)?  And why is "*it won't take much time to ferment*" said like it is a bad thing?

Comment: Thanks aashii. I've been trialing dosas for months now. I finally have all sorted out except the fermentation part. I read so many different tales from 5-6 hours to 12-24. Yikes! I've got the warm oven thing down pat now. I'm getting really good aeration but not volume (partly I believe due to the fact that I have to use too much water in my blender). BTW: what type of grinder do you use/recommend? A wet grinder, a stone grinder? I wouldn't mind shelling out for a stone grinder if I can use it for other things like chutneys.

Comment: @RayButterworth It's a lot like yogurt or sourdough bread. Too hot and you kill the cultures you are trying to encourage. Too cold, and they just don't grow.

Comment: @KillerSheltie, yes, but what actual temperatures are "*too hot*" and "*too cold*"? And more importantly, what is the ideal temperature and time?

Comment: @RayButterworth That depends on so many things including ambient temperature and humidity. I'm having luck with heating the oven to about 40 C. then turning it off putting the batter in (with a lid and a cloth over the lid to keep moisture in (I'm in a very dry climate), then leaving the oven light on. In the summer, I'd just leave it in the oven with the light on and not pre-heat the oven, but it's winter here right now and my house is rather cool.

Comment: @RayButterworth: 28 degree Celsius is the optimal temperature. https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01024419. Temperatures above 80 degrees Celsius is probably too hot https://www.vdu.lt/cris/entities/publication/1b44b55c-e63a-43e3-a294-70b77ac708a0/details